# Деятельность по перепродаже

Tags: названия

Чем является перепродажа билетов? Такого человека можно назвать спекулянтом, торговцем, купцом, продавцом (если за ним не закреплено место продажи, а он осуществляет сделки по телефону)?

Comment: Вопрос в чем? Можно ли назвать? Можно. Называйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Купец - лицо, владеющее торговым предприятием. (не подходит)

Торговец - человек, занимающийся частной торговлей. (скорее всего, не подходит, так как перепродажа билетов - нелегальное занятие)

Продавец - тот, кто продаёт. (подходит)

Спекулянт - перепродажа. (подходит)

Подходит продавец и спекулянт.

Comment: А что, частная торговля всегда нелегальна? Купец обязательно имеет помещение, разве он не может в палатке, на ярмарке сбывать товар?

Comment: Частная - наоборот, легальна. Частник должен зарегистрироваться в налоговой. Перепродажа билетов - не думаю, что это может быть легальным зарегистрированным бизнесом. Купец - в словарях везде пишут, что должен владеть предприятием - фирмой, компанией, организацией.